# fixed header and footer of table with repeater control

Tags: html, repeater

[image]I have this repeater i want to show scroll and fixed header and footer

below is code which i did to show in repeater

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Sr No.</td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Middlename</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Salary</td>
    <td>Join Date</td>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>DOB</td>
    <td>Designation</td>
    <td>Department</td>
    <td>HR Manager</td>
    <td>Reporting Manager</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
 
<tbody>
  <asp:Repeater ID="repEmpList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%#Container.ItemIndex+1 %></td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Middlename</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Join Date</td>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>DOB</td>
    <td>Designation</td>
    <td>Department</td>
    <td>HR Manager</td>
    <td>Reporting Manager</td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

now i want both scrolls horizontal and vertical with fixed header and footer

how can i do that?

Please help me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```css
thead, tbody { display: block; width:500px; padding: 0px; }
td {width:150px;}
th {width:150px;}

#thbold {
 text-align: center;
    color: red;
 }
td { padding : 0px;}
th { padding : 0px;}
tr { padding : 0px;}
table, td, th {
    border: 2px solid black;
  margin : 0px;
  padding : 0px;
 
} 
tbody {
    height: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: scroll;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: scroll;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
 
 
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<table style="width:300px;">


<tbody>
<tr id="thbold">
    <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th>
    <th>Head 3</th>
    <th>Head 4</th>
    <th>Head 5</th>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 4</td>
    <td>Content 5</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 4</td>
    <td>Content 5</td>

</tr><tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 4</td>
    <td>Content 5</td>

</tr><tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 4</td>
    <td>Content 5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

this is a very quickly done code, though this seems to cater to your needs. feel free to modify and style it as per your needs. Remember to set the thead and tbody as display type to block, and limit height and width of block, set overflow-x, overflow-y to scroll. Please feel free to ask for further clarifications

Comment: **@Vipin Mohan R Nair** sorry sir i am not understanding your code with my situation, if possible please post answer  including my code and format

Comment: you wanted a table with horizontal and vertical scroll right? @RaviSargam

Comment: **@Vipin Mohan R Nair** ya but with fixed(freeze) header and footer also..

Comment: i dont see the point of having a fixed header footer in a scroll-able table. it is possible to have fixed header and footer but with fixed horizontal table , but vertical will be scroll-able. @RaviSargam